# Como capturar um value digitado e usar para definir o valor de um atributo class (css)

Tags: javascript, jquery

sou leigo em js, então até para achar algo assim está dificil para mim. 
Estou querendo fazer o seguinte.
Digitar um valor número de 2 digitos num input e ao digitar, automaticamente, ir mostrando o valor em uma barra.
Essa barra é definida com "widht:0"
Se eu digitar 50, então o style ficaria "widht:50%"
Algo assim...

```css
.bar-porcent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 50%;
}
.bar-porcent span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 14px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='porc1' value="50" >
  <div class="bar-porcent">
      <div class="porcentagem">
          <span></span>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Para entender melhor, o layout está ficando assim. Preciso digitar o número e a barra já ficar do tamanho do que digitei
http://gtecprovisorio.hospedagemdesites.ws/grafeno-digital/sistema/cadastro-cedente/participacao.html

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer assim:

```js
const percent = document.querySelector('.porcentagem')

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(event){
  
  if(!this.value) percent.style.width = 0
  
  percent.style.width = (this.value > 100 ? 100 : this.value) + '%'
})
```

```css
.bar-porcent {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50%;
}
.bar-porcent .porcentagem {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<input type='number' value="50" max="100" >
<div class="bar-porcent">
  <div class="porcentagem"></div>
</div>
```

Lembrando que no HTML5 já existe uma tag para tratar esse tipo de comportamento: [`<progress>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress)

```js
const progress = document.querySelector('progress')

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function(event){
  progress.value = this.value  
})
```

```html
<input type='number' value='50' max='100'>
<progress max='100' value='50'>
```

Comment: Muito massa Renan vou estudar esse código, achei bem sofisticado rss. E esse método `input` já junta o keyup e change ao mesmo tempo!

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma opção simples, na humildade mesmo rss

Primeiro vc tem que passar seu `input` para `number`, depois tem que colocar um `max="100"` para o contador do `input` só ir até 100,  e min="0" para não aceitar números negativos pelo contador, mas isso não evita que o usuário digite um número maior...

Depois vc usa o `keyup` e o change caso o user use o contador do `input` para ativar a função que passa o .value do `input` para o `width` da barra. Tb coloquei na função um `if()` para caso não tenha valor nenhum a barra fique com 0 `width`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como falei é um JS simples, mas espero que ajude em algo...

```js
let inp = document.getElementById('porc1');

function mostraBarra() {
    let barra = document.querySelector('.bar-porcent');
    let x = inp.value;
    barra.style.width = x + "%";

    if (inp.value == '') {
        barra.style.width = "0%";
    }
}


inp.addEventListener('keyup', mostraBarra);
inp.addEventListener('change', mostraBarra);
```

```css
.bar-porcent {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 0%;
}

.bar-porcent span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 14px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
}
```

```html
<input type='number' id='porc1' value="0" max="100" min="0">
<div class="bar-porcent">
    <div class="porcentagem">
        <span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> Porcentagem na barra </title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .bar-porcent {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
}
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <input type='text' id='porc1' onkeyup="contador()" maxlength="3" onfocus="this.select()">
      <div class="bar-porcent">
      <div class="porcentagem">
          <span id="porcen"></span>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function contador(){
    var porc1 = window.document.getElementById('porc1').value;
    var barra = window.document.querySelector('div.porcentagem');
    var porcen = window.document.getElementById('porcen');
    barra.style.background=  'linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow)'
    barra.style.height = '30px'   

    if(porc1 <= 100){
    barra.style.width = porc1 + '%';
    }

    if(porc1 == '' || porc1 == 0){
      barra.style.width = '0%'
    }
    porcen.value = porc1;
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Usei seu código, ficou perfeito. Muito obrigado.
É só para o cliente aprovar, mas ficou show. Talvez o programador que assumir mude tudo, mas o efeito visual que eu procurava ficou perfeito.
Veja como ficou:
http://gtecprovisorio.hospedagemdesites.ws/grafeno-digital/sistema/cadastro-cedente/participacao.html

Comment: Obrigado, olhei seu site e vi quando digita apenas um `type='text'` ele da NaN em Total pode fazer um validação em JavaScript para  quando digitar apenas um `type='text'` ele fique 0. Ou some somente valor 1 e quando o valor 2 for digitado ele some 1 + 2.

Comment: ou pode deixar os 2 `inputs` formatados para começar com o valor 0 da também :)